# regex matching an open and close tag and a certain text patterns inside that tag

Tags: xml, regex

Here is a sample custom tag i have from a sitemap.xml

```
<url>
  <loc>http://sitename.com/programming/php/?C=D;O=A</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
  <priority>0.64</priority>
</url>
```

There are many entries like this and if you see loc tag it has c=d;0=a at the end.
I want to remove all entries starting with `<url>` ending with `</url>` which contains C=D;0=A or similar patterns like that.

The following expression matched the whole of the above specified tag

```
<url>(.|\r\n)*?<\/url>
```

but I want to match like what i had specified in the above statement.

How do we form regex to match such conditions(patterns) ?

Comment: you don't, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Fredrik, the answer is NOT correct. Regex can be used to parse xml but it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: @Fredrik: There's no problem with using regex here. OP isn't trying to parse XML, but a very specific subset of it that looks like the example in his post.

Comment: Have a look at [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I am not parsing xml but i need to remove those entries in sitemap using a text editor like dreamweaver. so that i can have a cleaner sitemap because i did not add a index.html in one of the folder in my site which has many subfolders. it is this folder i am making a sitemap http://vikku.info/programming/ .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
/<url>(?:(?!<\/url>).)*C=D;O=A.*?<\/url>/m
```

The negative lookahead guaranties that you do not match multiple  nodes.

See here: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/COVTptKtEU)

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am using dreamweaver to remove. anyway let met try that and will update here.

Comment: ok, dreamweaver might not support lookaround... but give it a try.

Comment: for dreamweaver it did not work. hope it would work in php... ?

Comment: Yes, it works in php. But you need to use the `s` flag instead of `m`.

Comment: what if we don't have the node name. I just want a regular expression to validate an xml node like this  <book>test</book>

Comment: try this: /<book>(?:(?!<\/book>).)*test.*?<\/book>/m

Answer (score 6):

It is not a good idea to use regex for XML. Depending on the language you should use some XML reader, extract the `<url>` node and then use regex to match the content of the node.
One useful language for querying XML data, which is supported by many XML libraries is [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

Comment: I am not using regex to parse xml but it is just my sitemap where it had all those entries because i did not have a default index.htm script in an important folder which had many sub folders. i wanted to update my sitemap without those extra c=d items so i need a regex to remove all those entries and to keep the sitemap clean. so i cannot write a program to remove the unwanted entries instead i just need a regex to remove that on the fly and want to update my sitemap.

Comment: Sometimes these libraries are overkill. For example, processing wiki-text that contains limited html-like tags. @morja's answer actually answers the question...

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use regex, this one:

```
<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)(C=D;O=A){1}(.*?)</\1>
```

will get you the line:

> http://sitename.com/programming/php/?C=D;O=A

I would then traverse up to the parent tag and do whatever I wanted with it.

Comment: It matched only one line and not that complete url open and close tag.