# Regex to match missing period (.) before end tag

Tags: regex

How to match missing period (.) before end tag using regex?

To make myself clear, here's a sample:

Samples need match:

```
1. text</… ></tag> ---> Where </...> is any tag and can be multiple end tags

2. text</tag>
```

Correct samples that don't need to match:

```
1. text.</...></tag>
2. text.</tag>
```

and I want to ignore something like this:

```
,</tag>   --> Where , can be any punctuation except period (.)
```

or

```
,</...></tag>
```

I hope someone can help me thanks alot!

Comment: I'm confused... you want to match places where you have a period before an end tag? Or you want to match places where you don't have a period before an end tag?

Comment: It would be more clear if you provided pure text examples, instead of mixing regex and text.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use `[^\.]`. This will match anything but `.` 
In your case you need to use `[^\.>]</`

Comment: how do I check if this is before </tag>? and before </tag> sometimes this may occur, </anotherTag></anotherTag></tag>, and </anotherTag> can occur multiple times before </tag>

Comment: Let it occur! if there is any `text</` in any part of your string, then this will check it

Comment: but I only need to match those text without period (.) before the </tag>. So you mean to say I will match text</otherTag> even if it is not before </tag>

Comment: What I mean to say is I don't need to match text without period if it is not before the </tag>. For example "this is a <b>text</b>". Your answer will match 'text', which I dont want to happen because it is not inside <tag></tag>

Answer (score 0):

`[,;:]` will match any punctuation *except* period. Extend at your leisure (as I'm not sure whether you want chars like apostrophe, quotation, slash etc.)

You can also negate that by using `[^,;:]`, where `^` stands for NOT in the character set.

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for reference.

Comment: the one confusing me are the multiple end tags (</...>) that can occur before the </tag>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368868/regex-matching-an-open-and-close-tag-and-a-certain-text-patterns-inside-that-tag

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done with my problem:

```
([^.:;(or)(and)\!\)()>])(\</.*?\>)\</tag\>
```

This will match text without period (.) before end :

```
text</otherEndTag>...</tag>
```

But the punctuation list will be ignored:

```
: ; ! ) ( > , or , and
```